# Python is not detecting installed selenium

Tags: python

I installed selenium and verified installation

```
User-MacBook-Pro:webscrape user$ sudo pip3 install selenium
```

> The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   The directory '/Users/user/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
>   Requirement already satisfied: selenium in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (3.14.1)
>   Requirement already satisfied: urllib3 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from selenium) (1.23)

then I tried to run a simple python file and I got this

```
  User-MacBook-Pro:webscrape user$ python vendorscrape.py
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "vendorscrape.py", line 1, in 
>       from selenium import webdriver
>   ImportError: No module named selenium

this is the python script vendorscrape.py

```
 from selenium import webdriver
 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
 import re
 import pandas as pd
 import os



 print("we are on")
```

Comment: Have you tried running your file with `python3` as opposed to `python`?

Comment: you are right @scales

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? I suggest you do `pip install` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used python3 instead of python

Answer (score 1):

First, you should install the package as your current user (without `sudo`):

```
pip3 install selenium
```

Second, you should use matching version for `pip` and `python` commands. Either use `pip` with `python` or `pip3` with `python3`.